# T-SQL - synchronize tables using CDC or Replication

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, replication, change-data-capture

Imagine the following scenario. I have 2 T-SQL queries over 2 tables with some inner joins. I need to run these queries in 24-hour period and synchronize the query results with other two tables (only changed rows).

My question is: What technology is more suitable Change Data Capture or Replication?

Thank you for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that somewhere in between your points of synchronization someone deleted the row

```
(ID, Name) = (15, 'John')
```

After that he created the row

```
(ID, Name) = (15, 'Smith')
```

Do you need:

1. Information that row with name 'John' has been deleted and now there
   is a new row with the name 'Smith'?
2. Information that 'John' is now
   changed to 'Smith'?

If you need former, use CDC. If you need latter use replication. Or better, use [Change Tracking](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280519%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (basically uses snapshot).

To sum it up, use CDC if you really need everything that has been changing over time. If you need only 'deltas', use change tracking.